# sudden wrong running sum value in query

Tags: ms-access, correlated-subquery

I am using a correlated subquery to generate the running sum called SumDemerits so I can check for data entry errors.
  the query gives the following which includes a copy of the original table:

```
    DemeritID   ID  DemeritDate Amount  DemeritType SumDemerits

83  42  5/23/2019   10  1   10
112 42  5/24/2019   -10 2   0
88  42  7/1/2019    2   1   2
89  42  7/9/2019    -2  1   0
90  42  7/10/2019   6   1   6
91  42  7/11/2019   3   1   9
92  42  7/12/2019   -2  1   7
97  42  7/13/2019   1   1   8
98  42  7/14/2019   2   1   10
99  42  7/15/2019   -10 2   0
120 42  8/8/2019    2   1   2
121 42  8/9/2019    1   1   3
122 42  8/10/2019   1   1   4
123 42  8/11/2019   1   1   5
125 42  8/12/2019   -2  1   3
126 42  8/13/2019   1   1   4
127 42  8/14/2019   -2  1   2
128 42  8/15/2019   -2  1   0
129 42  8/17/2019   0   1   0
130 42  8/18/2019   0   1   0
131 42  8/19/2019   4   1   4
132 42  8/20/2019   -2  1   2
133 42  8/21/2019   3   1   5
134 42  8/22/2019   2   1   7
135 42  8/23/2019   2   1   9
136 42  8/24/2019   -2  1   7
137 42  8/25/2019   1   1   8
138 42  8/26/2019   -2  1   6
139 42  8/27/2019   2   1   8
140 42  8/28/2019   1   1   9
141 42  8/29/2019   -2  1   7
142 42  8/30/2019   -2  1   13
146 42  8/31/2019   -2  1   9
147 42  9/1/2019    2   1   11
150 42  9/2/2019    2   1   15
151 42  9/3/2019    -2  1   5
152 42  9/4/2019    -2  1   3
148 42  9/5/2019    -2  1   1
154 42  9/6/2019    10  1   11
165 42  9/7/2019    -11 2   0
158 42  10/3/2019   3   1   3
159 42  10/4/2019   -2  1   1
160 42  10/5/2019   6   1   16
164 42  10/7/2019   3   1   19
171 42  10/8/2019   10  2   48
162 42  10/8/2019   10  2   48
166 42  11/14/2019  0   1   48
167 42  11/15/2019  1   1   49
168 42  11/18/2019  3   1   52
169 42  11/19/2019  6   1   58
170 42  11/20/2019  30  2   88
```

the running total SumDemerits works as expected until 8/30/19 when it suddenly gives a 13 instead of 5.  here is the sql for my query which just copys the original table and adds the SumDemerits column.

```
SELECT Demerits.DemeritID, Demerits.ID, Demerits.DemeritDate, Demerits.Amount, Demerits.DemeritType, (SELECT Sum(dupe.[Amount]) FROM Demerits as dupe WHERE dupe.DemeritDate <= [Demerits].[DemeritDate]) AS SumDemerits
FROM Demerits
WHERE (((Demerits.ID)=[ID]))
ORDER BY Demerits.DemeritDate;
```

html code that generates a version of the table you can cut and paste:

```css
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0pky">DemeritID</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">BoyID</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">DemeritDate</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Amount</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">DemeritType</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">SumDemerits</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">83</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5/23/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">112</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5/24/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-10</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">88</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7/1/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">89</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7/9/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">90</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7/10/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">6</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">91</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7/11/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">92</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7/12/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">97</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7/13/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">98</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7/14/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">99</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7/15/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-10</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">120</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/8/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">121</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/9/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">122</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/10/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">123</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/11/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">125</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/12/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">126</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/13/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">127</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/14/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">128</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/15/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">129</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/17/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">0</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">130</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/18/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">0</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">131</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/19/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">132</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/20/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">133</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/21/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">134</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/22/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">135</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/23/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">136</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/24/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">137</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/25/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">138</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/26/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">139</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/27/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">140</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/28/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">141</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/29/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">142</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/30/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">146</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">8/31/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">147</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9/1/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">150</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9/2/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">151</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9/3/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">152</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9/4/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">148</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9/5/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">154</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9/6/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">165</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">9/7/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-11</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">158</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10/3/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">159</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10/4/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">-2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">160</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10/5/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">6</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">164</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10/7/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">171</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10/8/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">48</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">162</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10/8/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">48</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">166</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">11/14/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">0</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">48</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">167</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">11/15/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">168</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">11/18/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">52</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">169</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">11/19/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">6</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">58</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">170</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">42</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">11/20/2019 0:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">30</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">88</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you post data as a text table instead of lines of code, would make it easier to import to a table and test. As it is, it copy/pastes as 1 long string of text. Try a report and use RunningSum property of textbox. See if you get same result.

Comment: Access reporting bugged at including a correlated subquery.  Recent experience suggests the solution is to base the report on a temporary table but that means the error will persist in the report.  trying to make a text table; not having much success.

Comment: using the running sum textbox in a report does avoid the error.  I'm not sure that is the solution I want.

Comment: did my best on that snippet.  the question now looks terrible; but at least the generated table will cut and paste properly

Comment: Okay, that worked great. Tested query and do not get the issue. Calculation is correct through 10/7/2019. However, there are two records for 10/8/2019 and both show the same sum.

Comment: Your snippet does not create ID field used in query. The snippet ID fields are not quite same as in the original dataset but doesn't seem important to result. WHERE clause in outer query doesn't make sense and doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: problem with using real data.  I don't care about the data after 8/30/19 for now.  it shouldn't affect the 8/30/19 data and is probably related to it.  I will check out the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

the problem occurs because the original query has a parameter ([ID]):
WHERE (((Demerits.ID)=[ID]))
the correlated subquery also needs to limit the rows it counts by ID or else it counts demerits from other ID's if they fall in the date range.   so change the subquery to:
(SELECT Sum(dupe.[Amount]) FROM Demerits as dupe WHERE dupe.DemeritDate <= [Demerits].[DemeritDate] AND [ID] = [ID])